# How to fix '(sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.' Issue?

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm utilizing Flask and SqlAlchemy. The database I've created for SqlAlchemy seems to mess up when I try to run my website and will pop up with the error stating that there's a thread error. I'm wondering if it's because I haven't dropped my table from my previous schema. I'm using a linux server to try and run the "python3" and the file to set up my database.

I've tried to physically delete the table from my local drive and the re run it but I still up this error.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from database_setup import Base, Category, Item

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database_tables.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

Session = sessionmaker()
Session.bind = engine
session = Session()

brushes = Category(id = 1, category_name = 'Brushes')
session.add(brushes)
session.commit()


pencils = Category(id = 2, category_name = 'Pencils')
session.add(pencils)
session.commit()
```

When I am in debug mode using Flask, I click the links I've made using these rows, but after three clicks I get the error

```
"(sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 140244909291264 and this is thread id 140244900898560 [SQL: SELECT category.id AS category_id, category.category_name AS category_category_name FROM category] [parameters: [{}]] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)"
```

Comment: I realise it doesn't answer your question but have you had a look over [Flask-SQLalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/)? It's built to handle some of these scenarios for you.

Comment: I haven't taken a look at it. I will definitely give it a read, thank you very much.

Comment: Failing that, AFAIK, you may just need to use `scoped_session` instead of `Session()`: `session = scoped_session(Session)`

Comment: I'll give it a roll, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use for each thread a session, by indexing them using the thread id `_thread.get_ident()`:

```py
import _thread

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///history.db', connect_args={'check_same_thread': False})

...
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
sessions = {}
def get_session():
    thread_id = _thread.get_ident() # get thread id
    if thread_id in sessions:
        return sessions[thread_id]

    session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
    sessions[thread_id] = Session()
    return sessions[thread_id]
```

then use `get_session()` where it is needed, in your case:

```py
get_session().add(brushes)
get_session().commit()
```